# Get Orchard ContentItem display URL

Tags: url, controller, routes, orchardcms, sitemap

When I'm in a View Alternate, I know I can get the display URL of a ContentItem by using:

`@Url.ItemDisplayUrl(contentItem)`

But I don't know how to get the display URL when I'm in a controller context (ActionResult). For sitemap purposes, I require the URL of the listed ContentItems.

I'm using the code below.

```
public class SiteMapResult : ActionResult
{
    readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    readonly ITagService _tagService;

    public SiteMapXmlResult(IContentManager contentManager, ITagService tagService)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _tagService = tagService;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

        string host = context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        xml.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");
        xml.Append(@"<urlset xmlns=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"">");

        var contentItems = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Latest, GetContentTypeNames().ToArray()).List();
        foreach (var contentItem in contentItems)
        {

            // The display url of contentItem

        }

        ...

    }
}
```

How can I get the ContentItem display URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *do* have access to Url helpers from a controller, through the Url property. So provided you don't forget to `using Orchard.Mvc.Html` on top of your controller file, Url.ItemDisplayUrl will be available to you.